# File path passed to File.ReadAllBytes method are overridden by prepending executing path

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-5, akka.net, topshelf

File path passed to File.ReadAllBytes methodsare overridden by prepending executing path

This is console application running as a service using TopShelf in debug.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"‪‪d:\ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent");

System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\FR\src\Service\bin\Debug\net5.0\‪D:\ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
```

StackTrace

```
at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
at FR.Engine.Actors.FileReaderActor.OnReadFileCommand(FileReadCommand command) in C:\FR\src\FR.Engine\Actors\FileReaderActor.cs:line 18
at FR.Engine.Actors.FileReaderActor.<.ctor>b__0_0(FileReadCommand command) in C:\FR\src\FR.Engine\Actors\FileReaderActor.cs:line 11
at Akka.Tools.MatchHandler.PartialHandlerArgumentsCapture`2.Handle(T value)
at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.ExecutePartialMessageHandler(Object message, PartialAction`1 partialAction)
at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.OnReceive(Object message)
at Akka.Actor.UntypedActor.Receive(Object message)
at Akka.Actor.ActorBase.AroundReceive(Receive receive, Object message)
at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceiveMessage(Object message)
at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Invoke(Envelope envelope)
```

For debug purpose I added line - refer snip for it's value

```
var fullpath = Path.GetFullPath(command.Path);
```

[image]

It works for a simple .net5 console app with Topshelf. So I suspect Akka.net causing this.

Comment: Wow never seen that one before, I can only presume that either there is no `D:` drive mounted or the `D` must be capitalized.

Comment: Did you try linux style slash / ?

Comment: @AlphaDelta Tried capital but still same result.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev Yes I did - same result.

Comment: It is very weird situation, your path is definitely absolute, looks like a bug.

Comment: Or maybe there is some restriction for working with root content, try moving file in at levest level one folder. What result it gives?

Comment: After looking through the dotnet core source there's nothing in the standard library that changes the path, it passes it directly into kernel32. This may be a problem with TopShelf. Either that or you're using a version of dotnet core that is broken, something else has changed the way `System.IO.File` methods operate, there's a bug or something esoteric happening in kernel32, or  `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"‪‪d:\ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent");` is never written in your code and you've erroneously modified it for this question and in doing so removed the issue for us to see.

Comment: please share a shot from your code

Comment: @AlphaDelta actual code in snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some non standard characters (not visible) are encoded before you "d:" in your string and that's why you have that behavior. If you rewrite your path manually (with the quotes) it will work.

[image]

In this example "filePathA" is copy-paste of your path and "filePathB" is the one I rewrote.

[image]

`filePathA` = 51 bytes

`filePathB` = 45 bytes

[image]

Comment: This is indeed the cause. I manually wrote the path and it works as expected.